# Binary Search array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

In this code, index of 0 (target) is not coming out to be -1, whereas of other numbers index ii coming out correctly. This is happening only with 0. What is the bug in this code?

```
    public class binarySearch {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] arr = {-14, -5, 0, 3, 23, 49, 74, 106};
            int target = 0;
            int ans = answer(arr, target);
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    
    static int answer(int[] arr, int target) {
    
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
    
        boolean isAsc = arr[start] < arr[end];
    
        while(start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    
            if(arr[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }
    
            if(isAsc) {
                if(mid < target) {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
                else {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if(mid < target) {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare `arr[mid] == target` vs. `mid < target`. Those can't both be right.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I think the idea is to assume the array is sorted in some direction, but check dynamically if it's increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the code is when you compare the value is `<` target. But currently, you are comparing the index with the target which will not match and it behaves differently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {-14, -5, 0, 3, 23, 49, 74, 106};
    // int[] arr = {106, 74, 49, 23, 3, 0, -5, -14};
    int target = 0;
    int ans = answer(arr, target);
    System.out.println(ans);
}

static int answer(int[] arr, int target) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length - 1;
    boolean isAsc = arr[start] < arr[end];
    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (isAsc) {
            if (arr[mid] < target) { // the fix
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        } else if (arr[mid] < target) { // the fix
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```